# Filtered-Accumulate

Tags: primes, lisp, scheme, sicp

Given the following task:

> **Exercise 1.33**
>
> You can obtain an even
>   more general version of accumulate
>   (exercise 1.32) by introducing the
>   notion of a filter on the terms to be
>   combined. That is, combine only those
>   terms derived from values in the range
>   that satisfy a specified condition.
>   The resulting filtered-accumulate
>   abstraction takes the same arguments
>   as accumulate, together with an
>   additional predicate of one argument
>   that specifies the filter. Write
>   filtered-accumulate as a procedure.
>   Show how to express the following
>   using filtered-accumulate:
>
> a. the sum of the squares of the prime
>   numbers in the interval a to b
>   (assuming that you have a prime?
>   predicate already written)
>
> b. the product of all the positive
>   integers less than n that are
>   relatively prime to n (i.e., all
>   positive integers i < n such that
>   GCD(i,n) = 1).

I wrote this code:

(Utility functions)

```
(define (gcd a b)
  (if (= b 0)
      a
      (gcd b (remainder a b))))

(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (divisible? b a) (= (remainder b a) 0))
(define (smallest-divisor n)
  (find-divisor n 2))
(define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
  (define (next x)
    (if (= x 2) 3 (+ x 2)))
  (cond ((> (square test-divisor) n) n)
        ((divisible? n test-divisor) test-divisor)
        (else (find-divisor n (next test-divisor)))))

(define (prime? x) (= (smallest-divisor x) x))

(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
(define (identity x) x)
```

Recursive:

```
(define (filtered-accumulate combiner filter null-value term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      null-value
      (combiner (if (filter a) (term a) null-value)
                (filtered-accumulate combiner
                                     filter
                                     null-value 
                                     term 
                                     (next a) 
                                     next 
                                     b)   
                )))
```

Iterative:

```
(define (i-filtered-accumulate combiner filter null-value term a next b)
  (define (iter a result)
    (if (> a b) 
        result
        (iter (next a) (combiner result (if (filter a) (term a) null-value)))))
  (iter a null-value))
```

Sum of primes between `a` and `b`:

```
(define (sum-of-primes-between a b) (filtered-accumulate + prime? 0 identity a inc b))
```

Product of relative primes less than `n`:

```
(define (product-of-relative-primes-less-than n)
  (define (relprime-n i) (= (gcd i n) 1))
  (filtered-accumulate * relprime-n 1 identity 1 inc n))
```

What do you think?

Comment: idk if you consider it contrary to this exercises purpose, or maybe efficiency is it a premium, but you might consider just writing a standalone `filter` function and composing them.  `filter` is a worthwhile function in its own write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're recursing only on `a` and possibly `result`, you can use an inner `define` that only changes these arguments.

When an item matches a filter condition, you can ignore it by recursing on the remaining items.  You need not give it a `null-value` result.  Putting these ideas together, we get:

```
(define (filtered-accumulate combiner filter? null-value term a next b)
  (define (rec a)
    (cond
      ((> a b) null-value)
      ((filter? a) (combiner (term a) (rec (next a))))
      (else (rec (next a)))))
  (rec a))

(define (i-filtered-accumulate combiner filter? null-value term a next b)
  (define (iter a result)
    (if (> a b)
        result
        (iter (next a) (if (filter? a) (combiner (term a) result) result))))
  (iter a null-value))
```

The problem asks for a sum of square of primes, like so (note the negated filter):

```
(define (sum-of-square-of-primes-between a b)
  (i-filtered-accumulate + prime? 0 square a inc b))
```

You can check for relative primes starting with 2:

```
(define (product-of-relative-primes-less-than n)
  (define (relative-prime-n? i) (= (gcd i n) 1))
  (i-filtered-accumulate * relative-prime-n? 1 identity 2 inc n))
```

Comment: Adeel - that is not how filters typically work.  generally those terms for which the filter function is TRUE are the ones that stay.  those that make the function false are filtered out. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/filter_f.html

Comment: @jon_darkstar:  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to address this

1. Write a `filter-accumulate` function like you are working on
2. Have seperate `filter` and `accumulate` functions and compose them (`filter` first)
3. Just use `accumulate` and work the filtering into your `combine` function (treat term like identity element when conditions not met).  Consider 'automating' this with a function that takes `filter` and `combine` functions and puts them together.

example of third method for (a)

```
(accumulate (lambda (x y) (if (prime? b)
                              (a)
                              (+ a (square b))))
            (range A B)
            0)
```

Answer (score -1):

'Accumulate' is usually called 'foldl'. So, your function is just

```
foldl f v $ filter g xs
```

in Haskell. Also, your algorithm is quite inefficent. If I was to find prime numbers, I would sieve them with prime divisors below the square root of current number. Here is an example:

```
primes = (2 :) $ flip filter [3..] $ \n -> flip all (flip takeWhile primes $ \i -> i * i <= n) $ \x -> n `mod` x /= 0

main = print $ take 10 $ primes
```

Result:

```
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
```